# How to trigger validation a specific field in Blazor Server and hide error message?

Tags: blazor-server-side

I have a zip field and when it is filled the city field is filled in programmatically. If this city field was validate before and the validation message was displayed the message is not hide after programmatically filling.

I tried this, but it does not hide the error message:

```
private async Task GetCityByZip(int zip)
{
    if (irsz.Length == 4)
    {
        shop.City = await GetCity(zip);
            
        FieldIdentifier fieldIdentifier = EC.Field("Telepules");
        EC.NotifyFieldChanged(fieldIdentifier);
        EC.Validate();       
    }
}
```